# Extjs 4.2 load form data with [] in name

Tags: javascript, json, forms, extjs

I have a extjs form with has names like

udField[1]
udFIeld[2]

I can save it on server side without problems. But when i want to laod the form it just wont populate the value....

Here is on example from the ud dield:

```
{
        labelSeparator: config.required == 1 ? ': <span style="color:red">*</span>' : ':',
        allowBlank: config.required == 0,
        emptyText: config.options.blankText,
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'udFields[' + config.options.udFieldId + ']', 
        flex: 0,
        fieldLabel: Ext.lang(config.display_name),
    }
```

And here is how i load it:

```
 Ext.getCmp('rootform').getForm().load({
            url: 'ajax/Freetext/Article/LoadSingle',
            waitMsg: Ext.lang('t_warenkorb_wird_geladen'),
            params: {
                cartarticle_id: cartarticleId,
                sid: config.sid
            },
            success: function (form) {
some checks and other stuff
}
```

I get the correct response from the server to this is the response json data:

```
amount: "1"
cartarticle_id: "xxx"
catalogpartner_id_freetxt: "xxx"
delivery_date: "15.04.2015"
description_long: "test "
description_short: "test"
manufacturer_aid: "xxx"
manufacturer_name: "xxxxxx"
order_unit: "PAK"
price_amount: "122.12"
remarks: "test"
supplier_aid: "test"
udFields[123]: "test"
```

but the damn thing wont load no mather what.... anyone has some ideas???

ps here is the whole json string with obscured data:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"catalogpartner_id_freetxt":"12","description_short":"test","cartarticle_id":"12","amount":"1","order_unit":"PAK","price_amount":"122.12","delivery_date":"15.04.2015","description_long":"test ","remarks":"test","supplier_aid":"test","manufacturer_name":"Datenbank feiger Text (@todo)","manufacturer_aid":"Datenbank feiger Text (@todo)","udFields[123]":"test"},"debug":["11.05.2015 16:58:20.860232 params:Array\n(\n    [cartarticle_id] => 312\n    [sid] => 132\n)\n<br><BR>"]}
```

Comment: May be define a reader and set `useSimpleAccessors: true`

Comment: Will try if i can achive somthing like that. if now then il have to define a custom renderer.

Comment: Aaaaa just read what you mean. i dont use a store, i use a form submit function. without any store attached to it.

Comment: Have a look: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-reader

Comment: Already on it. but i am lost how i could define a reader for my data to set the mapping right. like from udFields[1363] ->  to load from an array. because the number 1363 is also coming from the data. and is not predetermined

Comment: I found this article: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?78526-FormPanel-getForm-load()-and-arrays but cant figure how i could map to my data because   {name: 'data[Authority][name]', mapping: 'Authority.name'} is not applyable for my format. it would have to be  {name: 'data[1363]', mapping: 'Authority.1363'} wich is a variable to and not set in stone and ocures many times

Answer (score 0):

Well i could not figure out how to configure it. tried varios ways. In end i made a post sucess parser from an array.... 
Not pretty but only solution i could rely on....

```
  success: function (form, data) {
                if (data.result.data)
                    if (data.result.data.udFields) {
                        for (var key in data.result.data.udFields) {
                            var element = data.result.data.udFields[key];
                            var input = form.findField('udFields' + element.id);
                            if (input)
                                input.setValue(element.value);
                        }
                    }...
```